# Selenium webDriver, is it possible for actions to run out of order?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Selenium webDriver, is it possible for actions to run out of order? For example,

```
WebElement buttonElement = ....
buttonElement.click();


WebElement anotherElement = ....

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(anotherElement ).perform();
```

Sometimes not always, The 2nd doubleClick action is executed before the first click(), which causes tests to fail.

Comment: This is with Java, right? That should never happen to my knowledge. Can you share the html for the page and elements in question?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally that should not happen.

But you can improve your code by adding web driver wait.

You can initialize webdriverwait in this way :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement buttonElement = ....
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonElement)).click();
```

For **double click** :

WebElement anotherElement = ....

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(anotherElement ))).build().perform();
```

Try it out, this will make your test cases more stable.